# How to remove folder name from URL path without interfering links like the homepage?

Tags: html, .htaccess, server, url-rewriting, filepath

**Note:** the domain is not online it's made in localhost

Here's a complex problem I am facing right now on my project is that I want to remove the folder name from the URL from

```
http://www.example.com/pages/contact-us
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/contact-us
```

Hence removing the `/pages/` in this case -

This is my file structure-
[image: File Structure]

Now to access the files we have to access the `pages` then `contact-us` first so to remove this I have used this `.htaccess` code below -

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+pages/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^pages/)^(.*)$ /pages/$1 [L,NC]
```

When I use this the URLs can be accessed without using `/pages/` but the homepage shows

[image: 403 Forbidden]

So what should be the `.htaccess` code so to open the homepage without any errors and also please mention if this would kill my SEO and what's the fix?

**Please note if I need to tell you more, I have added these codes to the .htaccess file before adding the above code and it worked perfectly fine...**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

Options -Indexes

php_value display_errors 1
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Comment: What file are you expecting to be served from `/pages/`?

Comment: @MrWhite I want the URL to be http://www.hostedtools.com/contact-us from http://www.hostedtools.com/pages/contact-us as all the files are under the pages folder

Comment: Yes, but what about the "homepage" (that results in a 403). You request `/`, which is supposedly rewritten to `/pages/` - what file are you expecting to be served from here? `index.php`? `index.html`? Something else?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes that's the problem with this code does this code has any improvement to prevent this or a new replacement for this.

Comment: But what file are you expecting to be served when requesting the homepage, how is this request handled? By "homepage", I assume you mean a request of the form `http://example.com/`? If you don't have a `DirectoryIndex` document in the `/pages/` directory then you will indeed get a 403 response. I would assume you must have, but this is not clear from your question and we need to rule out the obvious. You also have an `index.html` file in the document root which would seem redundant?

Comment: @MrWhite Sir I only want to remove/mask the folder name i.e /pages/ under which all the files come so I am expecting the URL without the folder name and show that the pages are opened from the domain directly like www.example.com/contact-us or www.example.com/about-us or www.example.com/privacy policy please note the URL doesn't have any ?

Comment: Yes, I get that, but what about the homepage? Would the homepage also come under the `/pages/` folder?

Comment: No @MrWhite I have included the folder structure as image. Please refer I am still struggling, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simpler if all pages (including the *homepage*) were served from the `/pages/` subdirectory (which is what your code currently assumes).

(*Aside:* You didn't actually include the contents of your `/pages` subdirectory in your file structure, but if this subdirectory did not contain a directory-index document, eg. `index.php` or `index.html` (depending on the value of the `DirectoryIndex` directive) then you will indeed get a 403 Forbidden response. The same as requesting any directory without a directory-index document.)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule (?!^pages/)^(.*)$ /pages/$1 [L,NC]
> ```

However, if your homepage is supposed to be served from the actual document root and not be rewritten to the `/pages` subdirectory (like all other URLs) then you will need to include an exception in the above rule block. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule (?!^pages/)^(.*)$ /pages/$1 [L,NC]
```

To prevent requests for `/` (the document root) being internally rewritten to `/pages/`.

OR, make an exception for all directories (the document root is also a directory). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (?!^pages/)^(.*)$ /pages/$1 [L,NC]
```

OR, move your homepage (`index.html`) to the `/pages` subdirectory.

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite when I applied your code into the .htaccess (which is located inside the pages folder) actually worked very well

Comment: Sorry but the answer didn't worked first it worked again it didn't

Comment: Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

Comment: What is the URL you are requesting? And what is the underlying filesystem path you are expecting the request to be rewritten to?

Comment: I am requesting the homepage first then when I request homepage/about-us.html it is saying object not found in http://www.example.com/about-us.html error 404 what can i do now please tell I am unable to figure out anything now

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Does a request for the homepage work (which I assume is `/`)?  What is `homepage/about-us.html`? For other URLs, you should be requesting `/about-us`, not `/about-us.html`? You stated that all other URLs were working OK(?), the small change mentioned above should not have effected these requests.

Comment: I have inserted the 2nd no code of your inside the htaccess file(this file is inside pages folder) And the homepage works but when I request this page - http://www.example.com/about-us.html it returns an error object

Comment: "this file is inside pages folder"?! How many `.htaccess` files do you have? To rewrite requests to the `/pages` subdirectory (as part of removing the `/pages` path segment from the URL) this `.htaccess` file _must_ be in the document root - as indicated by your file structure "screenshot". (?)

Comment: i think your code is now sorted but its creating issue with removing .HTML from the files so could you add that code to remove the .HTML extension too.